# Grade computing program

Tags: python

I am learning python. The question is "Write a grade program using a function called computegrade that takes a score as its parameter and returns a grade as a string."

```
# Score   Grade
#>= 0.9     A
#>= 0.8     B
#>= 0.7     C
#>= 0.6     D
# < 0.6     F
```

How do I get the grades when I run this program? As I am not assigning the grades to any variable. Hence, unable to get the output.

```
def computegrade():
    if score >=0.9:
        print('Grade A')
    elif score >=0.8 and score<0.9:
        print('Grade B')
    elif score >=0.7 and score<0.8:
        print('Grade C')
    elif score >=0.6 and score<0.7:
        print('Grade D')
    else:
        print('Grade F')

score = input('Enter the score: ')
try:
    score = float(score)
 except:
    print('Enter numbers only')
```

No Error messages, but I unable to see the grades when entering a value

Comment: You are `print`ing the result of the function instead of `return`ing it. Then, in your running code you need to actually call it, by doing `computegrade()`

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing the grades because you're not telling python to run `computegrade`. If you do

```
try:
    score = float(score)
    computegrade()
```

It'll be done with.

Some observations about the `computegrade` method. I advise you to make it accept `score` as an argument

```
def computegrade(score):
    # grade calculations...
```

Although it works without this - as long as there is a `score` variable in the same scope, Python takes it - it feels counterintuitive to call a function that requires as score, not passing a score to it.

Also, currently your program accepts grades bigger than `1.0` and smaller than `0.0`, which is something you may want to `raise` an `AssertionError` in the future. I don't know if that is in the scope of your learning program, but having an

```
def computegrade():
    if score > 1.0 or score < 0.0:
        raise AssertionError('Scores must be within the 1.0 and 0.0 range!')
```

Is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
def compute_grade(marks):
    try:
        if float(marks)>1.0 or float(marks)<0.0:
            print("Invalid enteries")
        else:
            if float(marks) >= 0.9:
                print("Grade A")
            elif float(marks) >= 0.8:
                print("Grade B")
            elif float(marks) >= 0.7:
                print("Grade C")
            elif float(marks) >= 0.6:
                print("Grade D")
            elif float(marks) < 0.6:
                print("Grade F")
    except:
        print("Please enter numeric value")
compute_grade(input("Please enter your marks\n"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
sco = float(input('Enter your score: '))


def compute_grade(score):

    if score > 1.0:
        s = 'Out of Range!'
        return s
    elif score >= 0.9:
        s = "A"
        return s
    elif score >= 0.8:
        s = 'B'
        return s
    elif score >= 0.7:
        s = 'C'
        return s
    elif score >= 0.6:
        s = 'D'
        return s
    elif score >= 0.5:
        s = 'E'
        return s
    else:
        s = 'Bad score'
        return s


sc = compute_grade(sco)

print(sc)
```

Answer (score -1):

You aren’t calling the function; you have told Python what the function is, but not called it. 
What you need to do is

```
score = float(score) 
grade = computegrade()
print(‘Score :’, score,’ Grade :’, grade)
```

It is better practice to define your function so that it takes a parameter ;

```
def computegrade( score):
```

Instead of your current ‘def’ line, and then when you call the function:

```
grade = computegrade( score)
```

It is far better practice to write functions with parameters rather than rely on external variables.

Comment: True - I think I imposed my style - computegrade should compute (not compute and then display).

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to call the function.
The following is only a definition of the wanted function.

```
def computegrade():
    if score >=0.9:
        print('Grade A')
    elif score >=0.8 and score<0.9:
        print('Grade B')
    elif score >=0.7 and score<0.8:
        print('Grade C')
    elif score >=0.6 and score<0.7:
        print('Grade D')
    else:
        print('Grade F')
```

You need to call the function for it to be "activated".
You do so by writing:

```
computegrade()
```

So i would guess that the resulting code should look like this:

```
score = input('Enter the score: ')
try:
    computegrade()
except:
    print('Enter numbers only')
```

(no need to convert to float, the command input() does it for you...)

Comment: This is not Python 2, `input` returns a string